# How to solve error 122 from storage engine?

Tags: mysql

Got this from some mysql queries, puzzled since error 122 is usually a 'out of space' error but there's plenty of space left on the server... any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

The answer: for some reason Mysql had its tmp tables on the /tmp partition which was limited to 100M, and was filled up by eaccelerator cache to 100M even though eaccel is limited to 16M of usage. Very weird, but I just moved eaccel cache elsewhere and problem solved.

Answer (score 4):

Error 122 often indicates a "Disk over quota" error. Is it possible disk quotas exist on the server?

Comment: No as I said the account has no quota (unlimited) - maybe some other quota I dont know about?

Comment: Bravo sir! It turned out that some app did not do log rotation well and it amassed the log file of 65G and ate all of my disk space!

Answer (score 2):

Try to turn off the disk quota using the quotaoff command.

Using the -a flag will turn off all file system quotas.

```
quotaoff -a
```

Answer (score 1):

are you using innodb tables? if so, you might not have auto-grow turned on and inno can't expand the table space any more.

if these are myisam tables and it only happens on specific tables, i would suspect corruption. do a REPAIR on the tables in question.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this issue by increasing my disk size.
try df -h to check whether there are enough disk space on your server.